# Custom select parameters from linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

Maybe my question title is not the right one but ill describe whats my point.

Lets say i have database table with:

- Name
- Surname
- Phone
- Location

I can make query to get some results from this table  with this code

```
DALDataContext context = GetContext();
var result = new List<Users>;
var result = (from users in context.Users where Name = "test" select users).ToList();
```

But if i need only Name and Surname, this query give me all table information's(name,surname,phone and location). I think if i need only name and surname and make query to get only name and surname, this will increase my performance.

How to make custom query ToList() just for Name and Surname?

ASP.NET 4.0 C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a list of User objects with those fields populated:

```
var result = (
    from user in context.Users 
    where Name = "test" 
    select new User {Name = user.Name, Surname = user.Surname}).ToList();
```

To return a list of anonymous types:

```
var result = (
    from user in context.Users 
    where Name = "test" 
    select new {user.Name, user.Surname}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try with this:

```
var result = (from users in context.Users 
              where Name = "test" 
              select new User { users.Name, users.Surname }).ToList();
```